# Is there a way to auto-generate a JWG file/compile an Openscript file through ANT or some other build automation system?

Tags: java, ant, openscript

Openscript compiles the source code file along with its assets etc. and generates a .jwg file when saving the script through IDE.

I want an external method to compile the script, thus eliminating the need to open it in Openscript.

Is there a way this could be achieved through Ant or some other build automation software?

P.S.: There is a batch file bundled along with the software (osclti.bat) which achieves the purpose on Windows. I am specifically looking for something on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

OpenScript script can only be compiled in Windows. As of 12.3, there is no support to create/compile scripts in Linux.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I figured out a way.